# Twig fixed point arithmetic

Tags: php, floating-point, twig, ieee-754, bcmath

I'm trying to do precise arithmetics calculations inside a Twig template, but I am struggling with floating point's precision error and I can't find a way to solve this.

Is there a way to solve this in my Twig file(like a [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension) or my only way is to render my template directly with the result variable from PHP?

I leave a little example of what I am struggling with:

```
{% set x = 0.0089 %}
{% set y = 789 %}
{% set z = x * y %}
{{ z|number_format(32) }}

//7.02210000000000000852651282912120
//Result should be 7.0221
```

Comment: I would advise against doing this in the template. If you need fine and precise results, do it in the backend and feed the desired result to the view.

Comment: Or create a custom [Twig function](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) if you need this on more places in your view